# Unsetting a Chrome Policy

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome, high-sierra

So I used `defaults write com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory -bool yes` thinking it would set a mandatory policy for the global (machine) level, but it turns out I was wrong and it set a recommended policy. How do I revert that recommended policy back to an unset policy so it doesn't show as set to any value by Google Chrome? I tried a complete uninstall of Chrome by deleting the app and going to `~/Library/Application Support/Google` and deleting the whole `Chrome` folder and then reinstalling Google Chrome but the policy is still present and shows as set. Any help is appreciated and thanks for your help in advance.

I tried:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory -bool no`(only sets to false)

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory -bool 0` (still false)

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory -bool`(syntax of command error)

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory -bool null`(syntax of command error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quit Chrome, open Terminal and enter following (press Return at the end)

```bsh
defaults delete com.google.Chrome AllowDeletingBrowserHistory
```

Then start Chrome again.

See `man defaults` for details about the `defaults` command and its options.

Comment: where do I "use" that??? I don't know anything about programing or developing or computers at all, for that matter. I've tried everything else, PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: @Adrien Open Terminal.app, enter the command and press Enter